# Product UOM field not showing on Purchase and Quotations - OpenErp

Tags: python, postgresql, module, odoo

I'm using th purchase app on OpenErp.

I know this field is declared on `purchase.py` and called on `purchase_view.xml` but strangely it doesn't appears when i'm trying to add a new product quotation or purchase, don't get me wrong, the app works, but i find it amusing that this field isn't showing at all.

This is the field code on `purchase.py`

```
'product_uom': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Product Unit of Measure', required=True),
```

And the call on `purchase_view.xml`

```
<field name="product_uom" groups="product.group_unidadmedida" on_change="onchange_product_unidadmedida(parent.pricelist_id,product_id,product_qty,product_uom,parent.partner_id, parent.date_order,parent.fiscal_position,date_planned,name,price_unit,context)"/>
```

Both on the same class `purchase_order_line` btw

Any hint on this?

Answer (score 1):

Would please check you have given rights of "group_unidadmedida" to your user?

Comment: Well, this is a modification i made, i added 'group_unidadmedida' as an external ID via an .csv, but fact is, i can't see this uom even in the original app, where it's 'group_uom' instead of 'group_unidadmedida', and i can't see it even being the admin anyway :(

Comment: Gave the admin all privileges btw

Comment: then goto Settings => Configurations => Sales => Qutations and Sale Orders => Product Features =>  Allow using different units of measures  and check this and apply hope this help

Comment: go to settings => purchase => purchase order => purchase order =>  Manage different units of measure for products  and check it and apply

Comment: Yeah! that solved it! Awesome! thank you as always, you rule man!

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign this group to your logged user to see Unit of Measure in Purchase order. 
"Manage Multiple Units of Measure"

Go to the Settings --> Users --> Users. Open logged user record. Go to Access Rights tab and first tick the "Technical Features", save it, reload it. Again open the same user record from menu. Now you will see some more groups under "Technical Settings: separator. Tick the "Manage Multiple Units of Measure" , save it and reload it. Now again open Purchase order form and you will be able to see Product UOM inside it.

Comment: Already done that, it isn't the problem :) but thank you anyway!